# prove absolute integrability given square integrability

Tags: lebesgue-integral, normed-spaces

am trying to follow the outline of a proof in a book i am reading - must be missing something obvious, but would like to understand what exactly...

$f$ is complex and square integrable over e. g. [0, 1]:
$\int_0^1 \lvert f(x) \rvert ^ 2 dx < \infty$

the inner product $<f,f> = \lVert f\rVert ^2 = \int_0^1f(x)\overline{f(x)} dx = \int_0^1 \lvert f(x) \rvert ^ 2 dx < \infty$ and $\lVert f \rVert = \sqrt{ {\lVert f \rVert}^2 }$

now, the book says that absolute integrability would follow with cauchy-schwarz:

$\lvert<v, w>\rvert \leq \lVert v \rVert \cdot \lVert w \rVert$

and just picking $g(x) = 1$ as the second function. so, i'm doing

$\lvert <f, g> \rvert = \lvert \int_0^1 f(x) dx \rvert \leq \lVert f \rVert$

after playing with the root, it seems that indeed, since $\lVert f\rVert ^2 < \infty$ also $\lVert f\rVert < \infty$

but this just gives me an upper bound for $\lvert \int_0^1 f(x) dx \rvert$, not for $\int_0^1 \lvert f(x) \rvert dx$, which confuses me, since

$\lvert \int_0^1 f(x) dx \rvert \leq \int_0^1 \lvert f(x) \rvert dx$.

i think what i want to arrive at is exactly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality for the case $ p=q=2$...

my question now is: what am i getting wrong? what am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can let $g$ be such that $f(x)\overline{g(x)} = |f(x)|$ and $|g(x)|=1$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. $\overline{g}=|f|/f$ on the set $\{x \in [0,1]:|f(x)|>0 \}$, so $g$ can be chosen measurable. Then by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$
\int_0^1|f|dx = \left| \langle f,g \rangle \right| \leq \|f\|_2\|g\|_2 = \|f\|_2 < \infty.
$$
Hence $f$ is Lebesgue-integrable.

Comment: yes, i think that should work - thanks. feeling a bit foolish now, but the book clearly says, $g(x) = 1$. happy with $g = \lvert f \rvert / f $

Comment: In fact, you can prove that if the space $X$ has finite total measure, then for any $s\in(0,\infty]$, $\|f\|_s < \infty$ implies $\|f\|_r < \infty$ for all $0< r <  s$. For $f$ on a general measure space, the set $\{p\in (0,\infty) : \|f\|_p < \infty\}$ is an interval. I remember doing these as exercises in Chapter 3 of Rudin's R&C Analysis, but I don't quite remember how I proved them.